# How do I take datas from a JSON file and display it in an array in JavaScript vanilla(no Node.js or TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, import, export

So, basically, I have some datas in a data.json file. I want to export it in my JS file in an array so I can use it directly in my JS file normally. My JSON file is pretty big, so I can’t just rewrite all of it in a JS file. How can I do that? Is there like an import function or whatever? If it isn’t possible, what other language of storing data can I use?

I searched all of the Internet to find a way but I’m not able.

Answer (score 0):

If by "vanilla JS" you mean a modern browser, then you can use the `fetch()` API to get a JSON file that is hosted online. Like this:

```js
fetch('url_to_a_json_file.json')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: With vanilla JS, I meant just normal JavaScript, without any libraries or anything. But will I it work if my JSON file is hosted locally (in my folder)?

Comment: @GrugrubeCodes This will work without any libraries or anything, as long as it is running in a modern web browser. And yes, it will work for a locally hosted JSON file, as long as that JSON file is available through HTTP (for example, is being served through `localhost`)